# (Visual-) C++ Template type inference for string literals - VS 2010 vs VS 2017

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, type-inference

While trying to add a template specialization for string literals, I noticed a difference in behavior between the VS 2017 compiler and the VS 2010 compiler (both called from VS 2017)

This is the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    static const int a = -1;
};

template <size_t n>
struct foo<char[n]>
{
    static const int a = 0;
};

template <size_t n>
struct foo<const char[n]>
{
    static const int a = 1;
};

template <typename T>
int bar(const T& x)
{
#pragma message (__FUNCSIG__)
    return foo<T>::a;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << _MSC_VER << '\n';
    std::cout << bar("a") << '\n';
}
```

Run using the default compiler for VS 2017:

> ```
> int __cdecl bar<char[2]>(const char (&)[2])
> 1911
> 0
> ```

And run using the VS 2010 compiler:

> ```
> int __cdecl bar<const char[2]>(const char (&)[2])
> 1600
> 1
> ```

As you can see, `T` is inferred to be `const char[2]` for the old compiler, but `char[2]` for the new one. What changed? Is this a bugfix/bug in Visual studio or has the correct behaviour changed in C++11/C++14?

Trying with tio.run (both gcc and clang), it seems that VS 2017 is right, is this correct?

Comment: FWIW, string literals in C++ have always been `const char[N]`, but it's understandable if VS had them as `char[N]` for C compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple type matching.

Your function take a `const T&`. If I pass an integer, `T` will be deduced to be `int`, so the signature is `const int&`. Deducing it as `const int` would only be redundant.

As you can see, your parameter already as the const in it, so it is matched away.

Surely a MSVC 2010 bug that has been fixed over time, since older version of visual studio had a pretty low quality implementation of templates.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I was just wondering whether I missed anything, but reading your explanation makes the question seem pretty stupid

Comment: @Mathe172 Your question was well formed and legitimate, so there's really no problem.